# qt garbage collection and smart pointers

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers

Im thinking of starting using smart pointers in my qt work.The thing that confuses me how smart pointers would go with Qt garbage collection. The whole Qt stands on idiom that child QObject constructs with QObject* parent as ctor argument and therefore enables garbage collection.
For example:

```
     QWidget* mWidget = new QWidget(this);//Here we not only 
                                          //ensure that mWidget will be deleted  
                                          //when its parent is deleted, but also tell qt,  
                                          //that mWidget is not a window, but belongs to 
                                          //parent's layout
```

Now if i want to wrap mWidget into the smart pointer.

```
 typedef QScopedPointer<QWidget> WidgPtr;
 WidgPtr mWidget = WidgPtr(new QWidget(this));
```

But now when parent's dtor is called it will call delete on mWidget's pointer twice. First due to garbage collection, second when smart pointer dtor is called.

Of course we can construct mWidget without parent and then change some flags to turn off window behaviour or call setParent() (But then again mWidget will be deleted twice). But to me its too much to do such a complex initialization only to be able   to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.
Or maybe i miss something?
Thanks.

Comment: If the `QObject` child destruction mechanism works, why would you need smart pointers for them?

Comment: Because smart pointers offer some advantages beyound garbage collection. For example they prevent memory leaks if exception raised before deleting parent widget. For another example  they can prevent unintended copying of pointer object etc.

Comment: Object ownership is *NOT* garbage collection. There's no GC in Qt, or even C++.

Answer (score 5):

`QScopedPointer` and `QSharedPointer` are not aware of whether their target object lives or dies, so if you keep the smart pointer anywhere else than among member variables, then yes, in your case destructor might be called twice. That's why these kinds of smart pointers are badly suited for `QObjects` (but they can still be useful when your object doesn't have a parent).

If you need to keep a guarded pointer to `QObject`, use [`QPointer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpointer.html): it will become null once the object is destroyed, so you can `delete` it at any moment without fear of causing any mayhem. But remember that [`QPointer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpointer.html) will NOT destroy referenced object in destructor. In most cases you should build hierarchies of `QObjects` and just let the ownership system clean up the memory.

Comment: In Qt4, prefer QWeakPointer over QPointer, for better performance (read docs for both). In upcoming Qt5, I seem to recall QPointer is fine again, but don't take my word for it...

Comment: @hyde, thank you for your comment, I was not aware of it :) Apparently, it's true: `QWeakPointer` doubles as a replacement for `QPointer`. I wonder why would they keep `QPointer` at all though?